# Get next event based on timestamp within a sequence_id with SQL

Tags: sql

So basically I created an activity table with page_views on a website.
You have a Session_ID, a timestamp and an page path.
I want to be able to determine the next page for each row, if there is no next page than it should be blank. (see example)

Does anybody know how to achieve this with SQL?
Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You're looking for `lead()` analytic window function.

Comment: `select *, lead(page_path) over(partition by session_id order by timestamp) as next_page from t`.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `lead()` analytic window function

```
select
    *, lead(page_path) over(partition by session_id order by timestamp) as next_page
from
    t
```

This works thanks!!!